# When to use setter and getter if they are just used in one class

Tags: c#, class

I have a class and use private vars in that class, is there any need then for setter or getter?
I think they are just needed if I want to access the vars from another class right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do you use private variables with C# getter/setters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254434/why-do-you-use-private-variables-with-c-sharp-getter-setters)

Comment: You might get some clarity but this is entirely subjective.

Comment: Also keep in mind that private variables are not visible to a class inheriting from that class.

Comment: No you don't need getters/setter for state that is only relevant internally in the class. Use TDD, it will make it easier to understand how the public interfaces of your classes should be constructed.

Comment: @Calpis The question you linked to is different from this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're *sort of* right.

If you need to expose any of your private fields to other classes, you'll want to generate a property with the appropriate access modifier (public, protected, internal, or protected internal).

If you don't need to expose your private fields, reading from/assigning to a field directly is *usually* fine.

But even so, having private properties encapsulating private fields might be useful in some cases, such as:

- when you need to validate a value before assigning it to the field;
- lazy loading a value before reading from it, etc.